# MDX Query Optimization

Tags: mdx

I have a pivot table generated in Excel. I need to use the same MDX query which is used in Excel, I have extracted the same query from Excel which is like this -

```
SELECT {[Measures].[OQ],[Measures].[RQ],[Measures].[SQ],[Measures].[SRQ]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , 
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[PO].[Date].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[PO].[Priority].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[POL].[Container].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[PO].[Name].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[POL].[Num].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[PO].[Warehouse].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[POL].[Status].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[POL].[Factor].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}))
ON ROWS  
FROM [Purchases] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

This query returns about 3 lac records in excel, when I run this query in SSMS it gives error like "Server: The operation has been cancelled due to memory pressure.".

I am new to MDX, above query uses many CrossJoins, is there any way to optimize this query?

Thanks and Regards,

Amit Thakkar

Comment: Could you please add pivot table output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think its result maybe unusable almost for statistic reason
because of returning many rows.
but for optimization I suggest using 
NONEMPTY
front of your crossjoin